# UIGestureRecognizer with selector being called from another class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, selector

I have two classes that both add a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and use a selector to handle the code that responds to the gesture. Note: the gesture recognizer delegate probably does not relate to this issue but I'm including it in the code just in case it does.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let pinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchFrom))
        pinchGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc func handlePinchFrom(_ rec: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        // This method should only be called when pinching in GameScene scene.
    }
}


class Level1: SKScene, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // Same code here as in GameScene class.

    @objc func handlePinchFrom(_ rec: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        // This method should only be called when pinching in Level scene.
    }
}
```

In `GameScene` the `handlePinchFrom` method is called normally. After the user transitions from `GameScene` to the `Level1` scene, the `handlePinchFrom` method in `Level1` is getting called normally. However, the `handlePinchFrom` method from `GameScene` is also still being called when performing the pinch gesture in `Level1`, even though `GameScene` no longer appears in the Debug View Hierarchy.

Likewise, if the user then leaves `Level1` and transitions back to `GameScene`, the `handlePinchFrom` method from `Level1` is also getting called when you perform a pinch gesture in `GameScene`.

I guessed this may be caused by using the same name (handlePinchFrom) for both selectors. But I tried giving one of the selectors a different name and both of them still get called when I expect only one of them to be called.

Does anyone know why the `handlePinchFrom` method from `GameScene` would still be called after loading `Level1`, even though the program is no longer running the `GameScene` class?

Comment: "Does anyone know why the handlePinchFrom method from GameScene would still be called"  That's obviously because you've added an observer to the view controller and don't remove it.

Comment: @ElTomato I understand my use of `#selector` here is a way of getting an Objective-C feature to work in Swift. I confess I'm not too familiar with Obj-C. I assumed the selector would be removed once I transition away from the scene. Do I need to explicitly remove the selector before leaving the scene?

Comment: The gesture recognizer is added to the `view` and you are using the same view in the `Level1` scene. You'll need to remove the old recognizer with `view.removeGestureRecognizer(...)` in `willMove(from view:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code thanks to 0x141E's suggestion. See my updated code below.

I set up the gesture recognizer and grab a reference to it in `didMove(to view:)`. Then I use the reference to remove it from the scene's view in `willMove(from view:)`.

Now the gesture recognizer is no longer being called after my app leaves the game scene.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var pinchGrRef: UIPinchGestureRecognizer?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let pinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchFrom))
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)
        self.pinchGrRef = pinchGestureRecognizer
    }

    @objc func handlePinchFrom(_ rec: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        // Respond to pinch gesture
    }

    override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
        if pinchGrRef != nil { self.view!.removeGestureRecognizer(pinchGrRef!) }
    }
}
```